# Need div to fill gap between two divs

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">*header*</div>
<div id="content">*content*</div>
<div id="footer">*footer*</div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
* {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

There is a gap between the content and the footer's div. How can I set that the content's height must be all the space between the header and the footer?

The footer has to have the 'absolute' position to position is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Free fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Jfsak/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `display:table`, `table-row` options

`display:table` to `#wrapper`

`display:table-row` to `#header`, `#content` (width and height should be 100% here) and `#footer`

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative; 
    display: table; 
    width:100%
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background:#dbfcd6; display: table-row;
}
#content {
    width:100%; display:table-row; background:green; height:100%
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0; background:yellow;
    display: table-row;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6EKv/332/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is because your footer has a bottom:0 and its position is absolute.This will make it stuck at the bottom.

You should give your content a min height-and max-height like this:

```
#content {
background-color:red;
width:100%;
min-height:450px;
max-height: auto;
margin:0;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
```

}

Then change the position of the footer to `relative`

Check out this fiddle : )[Check me!](http://jsfiddle.net/xGUye/)