# A space between div?

Tags: css, html

I don't know why autospace exists between two divs. How can I delete this?

This is my code:

```
.mot
{
      width: 300px;
      max-height: 300px;    
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
}

.hai
{
      width: 280px;
      color: #FFF;
      background-color: #001c3e;
      font-size: 15pt;  
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; position: relative;display: inline-block; float: left;
}
```

This still results in a space between the div's (See this pic: http://puu.sh/7w2AQ.jpg)

```
<div class="mot">
    <img src="http://puu.sh/7w2AQ.jpg" width="300px"/>
</div>

<div class="hai">
    asdfasdf
</div>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: You are having lot of same questions are having solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176183/anonymous-white-space-between-two-divs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080765/need-div-to-fill-gap-between-two-divs are some of the few.

Answer (score -1):

It works perfect! I have tested your code in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/qfsPk/ and it is giving no extra spacing. I have used a `border` to test the spaces.

I think, there is some sorf of user-client's default settings.

My suggestion for you would be, to just check the properties in side the browser. Try using <kbd>F12</kbd> and checking for the Styling of the divs and these elements.

Comment: I have tested with google chrome and firefox, opera too. I don't know where extraspace comes from.

Comment: Try the browser's inspector!

Answer (score -1):

problem is `img` tag auto spacing use `display:block` to fix it

```
.mot img{
    display:block;
}
```